# Enable/Disable entire div in visualforce

Tags: javascript, jquery, visualforce, apex

I'm having this problem in visualforce.
I need to disable the entire div of my account if the selected donation would be Individual.. I try the hide/show but account name is required. so it's useless.
below is my script.

```
<script>
    $('#donation').change(function () {
        if ($(this).val() == "Individual") {
            $("#acct").prop("disabled", true);
            $("#contact").prop("disabled", false);

        }
        else
            $("#acct").prop("disabled", false);
            $("#contact").prop("disabled", true);
        });
    });
</script>
```

inputField

```
<div id="acct">
            <vs:column type="col-md-4">
                <h5><b>Organisation Name</b></h5>
                <apex:inputField type="text" value="{! acct.Name }" styleClass="form-control" id="acct" html-placeholder="Organisation Name" />
            </vs:column>
            </div>
            <div id="contact">
                <vs:column type="col-md-4">
                    <h5><b>Firstname</b></h5>
                    <apex:inputField value="{! cont.FirstName }" type="text" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Firstname"/>
                </vs:column>
                <vs:column type="col-md-4">
                    <h5><b>Lastname</b></h5>
                    <apex:inputField value="{! cont.LastName }" type="text" styleClass="form-control" html-placeholder="Lastname" />
                </vs:column>
            </div>                      
        </vs:row>
```

select option field

```
<select class="selectpicker" id="donation">
        <option hidden="true">Donation Type</option>
        <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
        <option value="Organisation">Organisation</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Please include all relevant code

Comment: Please check your code, you're missing a `{` after `else` (should be: `else {`, while you have just `else`).

Comment: still won't work >.<

Comment: <select class="selectpicker" id="donation" 
                                                    <option hidden="true">Donation Type</option>
                                                    <option value="Individual">Individual</option>
                                                    <option value="Organisation">Organisation</option>
                                                </select>